# Akka streams parse to Source

Tags: akka-stream

I want to parse

```
val flow : FlowOps = Source(1 to 10).map(_+1)
```

to a `Source` but looks like there is not a simple way. I have done this workaround

```
Source.fromGraph(

      GraphDSL.create() { builder =>

        val flow = Source(1 to 10).map(_+1)

        SourceShape(builder.add(flow).out)
      }
    )
```

Seems overkill to transform a simple stream to a graph just for get a simple stream again. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to use `Source(1 to 10).map(_ + 1)` as a value of type `Source[Int, _]`, right? But you don't need to do anything special for that, because `map()` already returns a `Source` of the appropriate type. If you write just

```
val source = Source(1 to 10).map(_ + 1)
```

then `source` will have type `Source[Int, NotUsed]`. You can check it easily by putting the appropriate signature explicitly:

```
val source: Source[Int, NotUsed] = Source(1 to 10).map(_ + 1)
```

I'm not even sure why you used `FlowOps` type annotation at all. `FlowOps`, as its scaladoc suggests, is a part of the akka-stream internal API and shouldn't be used outside of the library itself.

Comment: Ok, I'm a bit confused now and I think that it's because of the intellij docs. If I type: `Source(1 to 10).map(_.toString)` intellij shows this type: `Source[Int, NotUsed]#Repr[String]`. What thas it mean??

Comment: @RoberMP, this pattern is similar to the one used in Scala collections traits `*Like`, e.g. `TraversableLike[+T, +Repr]`. `Repr` designates (roughly) the type which implements the trait. If you open `Source` source (no pun intended), you will find that `Repr[O]` is defined as `Source[O, Mat]`, that is, a source with the same materialized value type as the one you're calling `map()` on but maybe with a different elements type.

Comment: @RoberMP, this is necessary because operations like `map()` are defined in `FlowOps` which is extended both by `Source` and `Flow`, but you would want `flow.map()` to return `Flow` but `source.map()` to return `Source`. Without some kind of `Repr` pattern `map()` operation on flows and sources would need to return some common type, which would be very unnatural and cumbersome to work with.

Comment: @RoberMP, and if you are confused by # syntax, that's how IDEA displays type members, i.e. types which are defined with a `type` keyword in classes and traits.